# Creating toggle button in Angular and typescript

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

Can anyone help me with creating toggle button for side navbar in Angular and Typescript. Thanks in advance

```
<nav *ngIf="nav.visible" class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 bg-faded sidebar-style-1 sidenav pt-3 mt-1 pr-0 pl-0">
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar-nav navcss">
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/home" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0" routerLinkActive="active"
                          [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><em class="fa fa-home mr-2"></em> Home </a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/profilesummary" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-desktop mr-2 "></em> Devices</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/caretakerinvite" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-calendar-o mr-2"></em><span
    class="sr-only">(current)</span> Caretakers</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/dosages" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-table mr-2"></em> Dosage</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/keytones" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-area-chart mr-2"></em> Ketones</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/admin" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-file-text-o mr-2"></em> Prescriptions</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/insurances" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0" ><em
    class="fa fa-money mr-2"></em> Insurnace</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-bell-o mr-2"></em> Reminder</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a routerLink="/" class="nav-link  h7 pb-2 pr-0"><em class="fa fa-edit mr-2"></em> Notes</a>
      </li>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Please read about event binding: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: I think you are looking for RouterLinkActive,  https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive (put in all yours links)